# Thymeleaf Master Layout Content Dynamics issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I have got some issue as I mentioned in the title.

This is my master page :

**Admin.html**

```
<header class="main-header">
    <th:block th:include="@{admin/fragment/header}"></th:block>
</header>
<!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
<aside class="main-sidebar">
   <th:block th:include="@{admin/fragment/sidebar}"></th:block>
</aside>

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <th:block th:include="${view}"></th:block>
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <b>Version</b> 2.4.0
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2016 <a href="">Studio</a>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
</footer>
```

`@{admin/fragment/header}` this code will include `header.html` in `admin/fragment` directory but this file will contain dynamic code for example ,a blinking icon if there is an incoming message , the name of the logged-in user etc. , I can do this at jsp

```
<c:import url="/header"></c:import>
```

`/header` will call `controller` and then `controller` call will `header.jsp`  but `thymeleaf` calls .html so my header will static content. I do not want to send data for header in each controller. I want to define specific controller for the header for it. How do I trigger this controller in thymeleaf ?